# Why selenium Firefox WebDriver cannot close browser after test

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using FirefoxDriver on a portable version of Firefox although I have an installed version of Firefox on the same machine. In my test setUp(), I have:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", TestEnv.FirefoxBinPath);
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Then the portable instance can be opened and the test runs successfully, but the browser doesn't close after the test even though in my tearDown() there is: driver.quit();

Can anyone explain why this could happen?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does it close 30 seconds after the test finishes or is your test simply not finishing?

Comment: @djangofan No, it does not close at all and sits on the screen even after all the tests have shown green success checks.

Comment: What happens if you do driver.quit() before the teardown, within the test method itself?

Comment: Still no luck, but if I remove System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", ...); the default Firefox (installed) will be opened and then closed as expected after the test is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must have something to do with the name of the firefox binary? Maybe WebDriver expects it to be "firefox.exe" and the .exe your running is different?  Or it could be something else along those lines.  Maybe the portable firefox doesn't connect to firefox system profiles the same?  I think your on your own on this one.  Why is it required that you use the portable one?

If you find no solution, you could always write your own process killer method:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pkill firefox");
```